Understanding the error 'LWR4009: A route definition must contain a "uri" property'
My team recently started managing an LWR Experience Cloud site. We have had two incidents where our production instance has stopped loading, and just a white page loads instead, each time with this error:
An error occurred during LWR bootstrap. Application @lwrjs/app-service/communities_app/module/amd/v/0_12_4 could not be loaded: Error: LWR3021: Error evaluating module "webruntime/routingService/v/1", error was LWR4009: A route definition must contain a "uri" property.
The first time we got this error, it was caused by a small function addition on an existing page, to scroll to a different location on the page when a link was clicked:
===HTML===
<a href="#" onclick={anchorJump} data-anchor-link="trip-image-gallery"><i class="fas fa-th-large"></i>&nbsp;View Gallery</a>
...
<div class="row" data-anchor-target="trip-image-gallery">
...
</div>

===JS===
anchorJump(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const targetSelector = 'div[data-anchor-target="' + event.target.getAttribute('data-anchor-link') + '"]';
        const targetElement = this.template.querySelector(targetSelector);

        if (targetElement) {
            targetElement.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
        }
    }

When we googled the error, we found this page, documenting the RouteDefinition object, and which says "You can't use # or *." So we figured it was the <a> tag. We rolled back the change, and the site came back up. But we didn't really understand the "why" behind this error.
The second time the site came down with this error message was not tied to a metadata deployment. The website just suddenly stopped working. Based on the viewId in the source where the error was being thrown, we were able to trace the problem back to a Custom Object page. We weren't using this page for anything (it was an R&D stub for our research on custom URLs), so we deleted the page, and the website came back up. We're not sure what happened. Could it have been caused by a data change?
I don't really understand what's going on here. What are "route definitions"? Why are they so fragile? Why does one bad route definition bring down the whole website? Why does this impact the published version of our production site, but not to the preview version of the production site or the published sites on any of our sandboxes?
